# trouble installing nesk/puphpeteer using composer require nesk/puphpeteer

Tags: laravel

i am having this error when running composer require nesk/puphpeteer

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires nesk/puphpeteer 2.0 -> satisfiable by nesk/puphpeteer[2.0.0].
- nesk/puphpeteer 2.0.0 requires psr/log ^1.0 -> found psr/log[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.4] but the package is fixed to 3.0.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions

Answer (score -1):

The composer logs has already detailed the necessary changes you might need –

The `nesk/puphpeteer:2.0` requires that the `psr/log` be at version 1.0.*.

You can try the following to lower your psr/log requirement:

`composer require psr/log "^1.0"`

Comment: I was able to downgrade psr?log, but now i have and other error:

 - nesk/rialto[1.2.0, ..., 1.3.0] require symfony/process ^3.3|^4.0 -> found symfony/process[v3.3.0-BETA1, ..., 3.4.x-dev, v4.0.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^6.0).

Comment: You have to determine which package should be the main anchoring package. In most cases it would be the framework – are you sticking with Laravel v9 or something equivalent. It might mean that you should look for alternatives to nesk/puphpeteer.